# Advanced Custom Field -- grabbing post_meta from previous post

Tags: post-meta

Say I have an acf called "show_this_tomorrow" every day (in a new post) I put some data into the field. And I want to show that data output on the next days post. I was thinking I'd use this to grab it, but it doesn't work in or outside the loop -

```
<p><?php echo get_post_meta( $prev_post->ID, 'show_this_tomorrow', true); ?></p>
```

Comment: how do you set `$prev_post`?

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the custom fields details added using ACF, you need to use the functions from the plugin.

Use [the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) to echo the value and [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) to retrieve the value.

Here you can use

`<p><?php echo get_field( 'show_this_tomorrow', $prev_post->ID ); ?></p>`

or

`<p><?php the_field( 'show_this_tomorrow', $prev_post->ID ); ?></p>`